# Simplify argument of Logs

Tags: simplifying-expressions, manipulate, expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following expression

```
expr=((-4 n (2 - 2 x1 + x1^2) Log[1 - x1] 
     + 2 x1 ((1 + n) x1 + 2 n (-2 + x1) Log[x1]))/((1 + n) x1) 
     + ((2 + 2/n) PlusD[-1, x1])/eps^2 - (((-1 + n^2) \[Pi]^2 
     - 48 Log[2]^2 + Log[16] Log[4096]) PlusD[-1, x1])/(6 n (1 + n)) 
     + (4 - 2 x1 - 4 PlusD[0, x1])/eps + (8 n PlusD[1, x1])/(1 + n));
```

Now for the 4th line containing `Log`, the term vanishes if simplified:

```
- 48 Log[2]^2 + Log[16] Log[4096]= - 48 Log[2]^2 + 4* Log[2]* 12*Log[2] = 0
```

A `FullSimplify` will do this simplification automatically.

```
expr //FullSimplify
(2 (2 + (-1 + eps) x1))/eps - (8 n ((-2 + x1) x1 ArcTanh[1 - 2 x1] 
+ Log[1 - x1]))/((1 + n) x1) + ((12 (1 + n) 
- eps^2 (-1 + n) \[Pi]^2) PlusD[-1, x1])/( 6 eps^2 n) 
- (4 PlusD[0, x1])/eps + (8 n PlusD[1, x1])/(1 + n)
```

But this simplification applies to all the terms and as a result in some other parts it simplifies and gives unwanted `ArcTanh`.

A manual way to resolve this problem would be to separate the term containing `Log`
and apply `FullSimplify` there, whereas the remaining terms are not touched by `FullSimplify`.

**My question: Is there any alternative way to resolve the problem i.e. to simplify the argument of `Log` which is an integer power of `2`?**

Comment: In the current case, performing the substitution will do the desired simplifications: `{Log[a_]*Log[b_] :> FullSimplify[Log[a]Log[b]], x_^-1 :> Factor[x]^-1}`.

Comment: another way is `expr // PowerExpand`